# Results reduced after adding left join

Tags: mysql, join

I am working with MYSQL and I am having some troubles getting the expected results I want.

I am working with 4 tables right now...

```
matchopponents
--------------
opp1id
opp2id 
matchid

matches
-------------
id 
title

players
------------
id
playeralias

ratings 
------------
ratingid
ratingvalue
matchid
```

I need a query that will select each row from the matchopponents table, distinguish the playeralias based on the opp1id and opp2id, grab the match title from the matches table, and then round the average total ratings for each respected match in the matchopponent table. The query I have so far is getting close to the expected result however it only returns one row from the matchopponents table. Currently I have 2 rows in the matchopponents table:

opp1id opp2id  matchid
2       3        11
4       5        12

The following query returns

Matchtitle                 Player1           Player2    Rating 
MarineKing vs Ryung        MarineKing        Ryung        3

This is great for the first row... (opp1id 2, opp2id 3, matchid 11)

But nothing is being returned for the second row... When I remove the LEFT JOIN ratings,
Both are being displayed. I have ensured all the proper ID's are in place and correct. 
:(

Any help on why this is happening would greatly be appreciated :)

```
SELECT 
m.title AS "Match Title",
p1.playeralias AS "Player 1",
p2.playeralias AS "Player 2",
ROUND(IFNULL(AVG(r.ratingvalue), 1)) AS "Rating"
FROM 
matchopponents AS MO
JOIN matches AS m ON mo.matchid = m.id
JOIN players AS p1 ON mo.opp1id = p1.id 
JOIN players AS p2 ON mo.opp2id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN ratings r
ON 
r.matchid = mo.matchid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `GROUP BY` clause on your original query:

```
SELECT 
  m.title AS "Match Title",
  p1.playeralias AS "Player 1",
  p2.playeralias AS "Player 2",
  ROUND(IFNULL(AVG(r.ratingvalue), 1)) AS "Rating"
FROM  matchopponents AS MO
JOIN matches AS m ON mo.matchid = m.id
JOIN players AS p1 ON mo.opp1id = p1.id 
JOIN players AS p2 ON mo.opp2id = p2.id
LEFT JOIN ratings r
  ON r.matchid = mo.matchid
GROUP BY m.title, p1.playeraliasp2.playeralias;
```

Since you are aggregating the results (`avg()`), then you want to aggregate over all of the rows. MySQL is different because it allows the use of an aggregate function without including the other columns in the select list to be aggregated or grouped, but the results will not necessarily be correct.

Using the aggregate function with the GROUP BY will make sure that you will always return the expected value for the other columns in the select list. When you do not GROUP BY or aggregate the items in the SELECT list, you might return unexpected results. (see [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
m.title AS "Match Title",
p1.playeralias AS "Player 1",
p2.playeralias AS "Player 2",
(SELECT ROUND(IFNULL(AVG(r.ratingvalue), 1)) FROM ratings r WHERE r.matchid = mo.matchid LIMIT 1) AS "Rating"
FROM 
matchopponents AS MO
JOIN matches AS m ON mo.matchid = m.id
JOIN players AS p1 ON mo.opp1id = p1.id 
JOIN players AS p2 ON mo.opp2id = p2.id
```

Comment: Subquery is very usefull in this situation